# WooCommerce is complaining about wrong consumer key

Tags: wordpress, curl, woocommerce

I have WordPress 4.4, WooCommerce 2.4.12. I am using cURL to connect to the WooCommerce API by SSL. I've put these codes into Mac Terminal window:

```
curl https://mywebsite.com/wc-api/v3/products -u consumer_key:consumer_secret
```

The consumer key and the secret are copied directly from the website. But when I hit enter, it shows me this:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"Consumer Secret is invalid"}]}
```

I don't know why it happens. But the key and the secret are definitely correct. Is there a workaround or a way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Try `curl https://www.example.com/wc-api/v3/orders?consumer_key=123&consumer_secret=abc` some web servers have problem parsing the authentication header.

Comment: Are you sure you are using HTTPS ? If you are using HTTP you have to OAuth 1.0 one legged authentication, not just basic Auth.

Comment: Any solution so far? I am working with NodeJS API for Woocommerce and can work fine with http based websites. But https says `invalid consumer secret`. Don't know what is wrong. The same key and secret pull data within the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I ended up here because I still face the same problem.

This page lists probable causes and solutions for the problem:

https://robotninja.com/blog/fix-common-woocommerce-rest-api-issues/

The culprit seems to be that the `Auth` header of Basic Authentication may not be passed all the way through to WooCommerce, i.e. PHP.
The article suggests that it could be caused by plugins responsible for caching, or that changes to the sever's .htaccess file may be required.

Comment: The url's broken update

Comment: @VikrantShah just checked and the link works for me.

Comment: Yes the link is now active but I am not sure hat is causing this. Sorry!